# What Yu-Gi-Oh! cards are being referred to by Sueharu when describing Kuro?

Tags: yu-gi-oh, osamake

Actually, I believe I know all 4 except #3 which might be a mistake.

1

Ultimate Kuroha

[image]

It's a fusion with 4500 ATK and 3800 DEF. It's obviously Blue-Eyes Ultimate Dragon and related cards in Seto Kaiba's deck like Blue-Eyes Alternative Ultimate Dragon, Neo Blue-Eyes Ultimate Dragon, et al.

[image]

2

Pure Kuroha

[image]

Less obvious but looking up ATK 2000 and DEF 1700 gives Dark Magician Girl and related cards in Yugi's / Atem's deck like Apprentice Illusion Magician, Toon Dark Magician Girl, Palladium Oracle Mana, et al.

[image]

3

(we'll get to this next)

4

Alter Kuroha

[image]

It's an illusion monster with 0 ATK and 0 DEF. It's Relinquished or related cards in Maximillion Pegasus's deck like Thousand-Eyes Idol, Thousand-Eyes Restrict, [Dark-Eyes Illusionist (at least in the anime)](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Dark-Eyes_Illusionist_(anime)), Millennium-Eyes Restrict, et al.

[image]

3

Sergeant Kuroha

[image]

This may be beyond generation 1 yu-gi-oh! My best bet is that it's a mistake that it should be 2000 DEF instead of 1000 DEF even if it's 2500 ATK s.t. this represents Elemental Hero Neos from generation 2 Yu-Gi-Oh! GX.

[image]

The 2500 ATK and 1000 DEF database gives [this](https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=1&sess=1&rp=10&mode=&sort=1&keyword=&stype=1&ctype=&othercon=2&starfr=&starto=&pscalefr=&pscaleto=&linkmarkerfr=&linkmarkerto=&link_m=2&atkfr=2500&atkto=2500&deffr=1000&defto=1000). Maybe if it's GX, then it's Elemental HERO Neos Knight.

[image]

Gen 1 cards include Guardian Grarl, Krystal Dragon, Wattaildragon. Maybe Guardian Grarl.

[image]

Or maybe it should be 2100 DEF, so it's Dark Magician.

Comment: What on earth are you even asking?

Comment: @Wondercricket What Yu-Gi-Oh! cards are being referenced? Each of them seems to refer to a particular card in the 1st gen yugioh.

Answer (score -3):

Or wait if it's warrior ritual, then maybe it's Black Luster Soldier, and indeed 'soldier' is close to 'sergeant.' Black Luster Soldier DEF = 2500 = ATK of Sergeant Kuroha.

[image]